# How can I read code that contains variables inside an xml tag?

Tags: xml

I have an xml document that contains parameters and variables declaration inside a tag. This xml is produced automatically by exporting a job created in DataStage IBM ETL tool.

```
<Record Identifier="V369S3" Type="TransformerStage" Readonly="0">
<Property Name="Name">TR_VLD_AR_flow2</Property>
<Property Name="NextID">4</Property>
<Property Name="InputPins">V369S3P3</Property>
<Property Name="OutputPins">V369S3P2</Property>
<Collection Name="MetaBag" Type="MetaProperty">
<SubRecord>
<Property Name="Owner">APT</Property>
<Property Name="Name">TrxGenCode</Property>
<Property Name="Value" PreFormatted="1">//
// Generated file to implement the 
V369S3_JobExtVld_10_AR_RCRD_MS_2_AR_X_AR_RLTNP_Flow_3_TR_VLD_AR_flow2 
transform operator.
//
// define our input/output link names
inputname 0 Lnk_Main_33;
outputname 0 Lnk_Main_Filter;

global {
// Job parameter declaration
ustring[] TRANSFORMER_ParamSetMasterInitParam_ParamReferenceDate;
int64 ParamRejTimeWindow;
}

initialize {
// define our control variables
int8 RowRejected0;
int8 NullSetVar0;


// declare our intermediate variables for this section (1)
string InterVar0_0;
string InterVar0_1;
ustring InterVar0_3;
ustring InterVar0_4;

...more code and then
finish {
}
</Property>
```

Is this a special kind of xml? How can I read a variable's value from this part of code inside xml tag?

```
if (null(Lnk_Main_33.LKP_SRC_STM_ID)) {
  StageVar0_w1 = InterVar0_14;
} else {
  StageVar0_w1 = InterVar0_3;
}
//;
```

Comment: Do not post text as images, post them as text.

Comment: The tag closes properly..there was a big part of code before that end tag I didnt put the whole code.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a special kind of xml?

No more special than any other kind of XML.

> How can I read a variable's value from this part of code inside xml tag?

1. Pick a programming language
2. Select an XML parser library for that programming language
3. Use them to extract the text content of the appropriate `Property` element
4. Select a parser of *whatever that programming language is* library for the programming language you are using. (This is tricky. One might not exist. You might want to start here so you can make a more informed choice at step 1. You might have to resort to writing your own parser or hacking together something with regular expressions.)
5. Use that to extract the value of the source code assigns to the variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try the suggested approach.